# How long can Bastion tank Bob in Sentry while self-healing?

Tags: overwatch

Assumptions:

- Bob and Bastion both start at full health
- Bob only fires at Bastion from the start up to the time he disappears
- Nobody else fires at Bob or Bastion
- Bastion starts with a full healing meter
- Bastion is already in Sentry mode when Bob engages
- Bastion only self-heals; does not fire at Bob
- Bastion starts self-healing the moment he takes enough damage to use a full tick of healing
- Bastion can tap-heal if that makes a difference in extending his time to live

Will Bastion die before Bob disappears? If yes, how long will it take for Bastion to die?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Numbers:

- B.O.B. fires a total of 78 bullets that each deal 14 damage every 8 seconds.

  - Damage per second: 112 (88 against armour)
  - Total damage: 1092
- Bastion has 300 health (100 of which is armour) and takes 20% less damage while in Sentry or Tank configurations.

  - Armour reduces damage by half with a max reduction of 3; other damage modifications happen first.
- Bastion's Self-Repair heals 15 health per tick (prorated over how long you held the button for the last tick, the ticking appears to be on a global timer rather than when you begin the ability) at 5 ticks per second for a maximum of 4 seconds.

  - Total healing: 300
  - For simplicity we'll assume each tick gets 15 healing (none of that proration madness).
- When Bastion's healing is fully depleted, the healing recharges to full after 7 seconds, and it must be 20% full to use at all.

  - This equates to needing 1.4 seconds of recharge to get 4 ticks for 60 healing, for 42+6/7 healing per second.

Result:

- With both the armour and transofmration resistances applied, Bastion will take 70.4 damage per second and thus out-heal B.O.B. for 4 seconds.
- Once Bastion's healing runs out, he'll run out of armour at about 5.5s (from when B.O.B. started firing) and start taking 89.6 damage per second.
- Slightly earlier than that, Bastion will get some healing back, so he'll outheal B.O.B. for a bit before dropping back down again.
- The math after this point gets real messy. But if I've done it right:

  - Bastion will get his second short healing burst at about 7.6s, when he has 103.6 HP. His next heal burst after that would be 9.8s.
  - Bastion runs out of HP at 9.375s.
  - B.O.B. lasts for 10 seconds after he starts firing.

Conclusion 1: B.O.B. will get Bastion eventually 1v1, but it will take almost all his time.

Conclusion 2: If it is 1v1, Bastion should just shoot B.O.B., he'll will shred him in 2+2/3 seconds while surviving for 4.5s if he doesn't heal.

(all numbers from [the Overwatch part of Gamepedia](https://overwatch.gamepedia.com))

Comment: Thanks for doing the math. I like conclusion 2 a lot ;)